# Opening existing project in Delphi 10.2 reports error that "Class TBarSeries not found."

Tags: teechart, delphi-10.2-tokyo

This is a strange one, and is related to the *Delphi IDE* environment, but I'm hoping someone has some insight, cos I'm at a loss.

Basically, the problem is that I'm now in a situation where any project I create that uses a `TChart` with a `TBarSeries` gives me the **"Class TBarServices not found"** error when I re-open it from a fresh start of the IDE.

As an example, currently if I do the following:

- Create a new VCL forms application,
- add a `TChart` component to the form,
- edit the chart through the designer and add a Series, choosing Bar as the type.
- Build the project,
- run it, everything is fine.
- Close the IDE and restart it.
- Open the previously saved project. Immediately get the Error Reading Form message about **Class TBarSeries not found**.

But if I then:

- Close the broken project without saving, and leave the IDE running.
- Create a new VCL form with or without a project,
- add the `TChart` and bar Series to the form,
- close the form/application without saving.
- Reopen the previously saved project that threw the error. **No error any more**.

Creating a new `TForm` with a `TChart` and `TBarSeries` is changing the *Delphi IDE* in some way that is not persistent, so that the next time the IDE is started, those projects no longer load properly.

I have included `VCLTee` in the *Unit Scope Names*, but the Enterprise version of *Delphi 10.2* does not include the source for these components, so there are no additional paths I can add to the *Library Path*.

Once I have created a new form and set up the chart, everything is fine with any project that uses the `TBarSeries` so long as I don't close the IDE, so that's the workaround I currently employ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use DevExpress?
I had the same problem when DevExpress Printing System for DBTeeChart was installed. 
Probably DevExpress uses old version of TeeChart different than this installed by you.
I just disabled this DevExpress Printing System and now it's OK.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as it seems to be the problem. If I turn off all the ExpressPrinting packages prior to loading my large project (after I turned those packages off in the DPROJ), I no longer the error about "Class TBarServices not found". The only problem I have is that every time I open a new instance of the IDE, these packages are enabled again, even after "removing" them.